# Throwing Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, class

I'm not understanding why my compiler is showing an illegal argument exception when the argument is valid. Any ideas?

```
public class bikeBrakeTest {
   public enum BrakeType {Caliper, Cantilever, LinearPull, Disc };
   public BrakeType brakes;

  public bikeBrakeTest() //Defualt Constructor
  {
    brakes = BrakeType.Caliper;
  }

  public bikeBrakeTest(BrakeType aBrake) //Parameterized Constructor
  {
    setBrakes(aBrake);
  }


  public void setBrakes (BrakeType aBrake) //Mutator Method "set"
  {
    if (aBrake.equals("Caliper") || aBrake.equals("Cantilever") || aBrake.equals("LinearPull") || aBrake.equals("Disc"))
    {
      brakes = aBrake;
    }
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid");
  }
}
```

And then my tester is..

```
public class testing {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        bikeBrakeTest myBike = new bikeBrakeTest();
        myBike.setBrakes(bikeBrakeTest.BrakeType.Caliper);
}
}
```

Comment: 1. It's not the compiler. 2. Why do you think a `BrakeType` will ever be equal to a `String`?

Comment: `aBreak` is not equal to `"Caliper"`.  It might be equal to `BrakeType.Caliper`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly compare `enum` to `string` `'Caliper'`, rather you need to use `aBrake == BrakeType.Caliper` for comparison as shown below.

```
public void setBrakes (BrakeType aBrake) {
       if (aBrake == BrakeType.Caliper || 
          aBrake == BrakeType.Cantilever || 
          aBrake == BrakeType.LinearPull || 
          aBrake == BrakeType.Disc) {
                  brakes = aBrake;
        } 
       else throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!